# Is the $L^1$ limit of bounded functions again bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$. Assume $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that $|f|\leq 1$ almost everywhere ?

I would do it like this:
If $f_n\to u$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we can pass to a subsequence so that $f_{n_k}\to f$ a.e. and hence $|f|\leq 1$ a.e..

Comment: Ok. Why do you stop? You got it.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. Thanks! What do you mean by "stop " ?

Comment: suppose that $|f(x_0)|>1$. by convergence, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, 1-|f(x_0)|<|f_n(x_0)|-|f(x_0)|<|f(x_0)|-1$ by the triangle inequality, which implies $1<|f_n(x_0)|$ contradicting the fact that $|f_n(x)|\in [0,1]$ for all $n$. so $|f|\leq 1$ everywhere...

Comment: You only need to argue that $u=f$ almost everywhere and you are done. (Believe in yourself, don't rely on somebody else approving your work. This is a piece of advice I often give to myself).

Comment: You're right, that is truly a valuable advice!